# Nominatim reverse geocoding directly over postgresql tables

Tags: postgresql, openstreetmap, reverse-geocoding, nominatim

As I advanced in the title, I would like to make queries directly against my database, instead of using the URL get service provided by Nominatim.

I have my own Nominatim instance running in a **Debian** machine, and is supposed I'm working over **up-to-date versions**.

The thing is that I would like to **test multiple nodes at the same time** in order to get common information or relations between them. As I gave hundreds of tables in my Nominatim db, and doesn't look like querying them is trivial at all, I'm asking for some ideas.

At the end, I will probably just use the tool over **way's nodes**, so maybe there is a trick or some *specific tables* where I can match them.

Comment: Did you already tried to take a look at Nominatim's code? In the end the webfrontend also just queries the database.

Comment: Do you mean the source shown here?: https://github.com/twain47/Nominatim